# Different models in CakePHP rating plugin

Tags: php, jquery, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I have a site that listings mp3 files in various categories. The site is in CakePHP and I am using the CakePHP star rating plugin for the rating functionality. The songs are categorized based on Albums, Singer and Music director so I need to implement rating for each of these. The rating plugin now I am using has an option for specify the model. It's model class is something like this :

```
class Rating extends Model {
  var $name = 'Rating';

  var $validate = array(
    'user_id'  => array(
      'rule' => array('maxLength', 36),
      'required' => true
    ),
    'model_id' => array(
      'rule' => array('maxLength', 36),
      'required' => true
    ),
    'model'    => array(
      'rule' => 'alphaNumeric',
      'required' => true
    )
  );


  var $hasMany = array(
    'Rating' => array(
      'className'  => 'Rating',
      'foreignKey' => 'model_id',
      'conditions' => array('Rating.model' => 'rating'),
      'dependent'  => true,
      'exclusive'  => true
    )
  ); 
}
```

It has option to specify the model name and model id so I think my issue will be fixed if I will be able to specify the model name or any other parameter along with this Array. As I am newbie in CakePHP, someone please help me to find a solution.

Please check the rating plugin I am talking about here:

http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/schneimi/2010/08/19/ajax-star-rating-plugin-1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **$hasMany** attribute definition needs to go in the model you would like to rate. So for **Album**, it would look something like:

```
/**
* Album Model
*/
class Album extends Model
{
  var $name = 'Album';

  var $hasMany = array(
    'Rating' => array(
      'className'   => 'Rating',
      'foreignKey'  => 'model_id',
      'conditions' => array(
        'Rating.model' => 'Album'
      ),
      'dependent'   => true,
      'exclusive'   => true
    )
  ); 
}
```

Comment: So you mean I need to crate another model called Albun like the Ratings model of the plugin and put the code there or put this code in the model that fetches the Album..? and also after giving this how can i tell the in the code that it has to use this model..? I also need to pass song/album/music director Id along with the rating.

Comment: Yes, you need to create Models for Album, Singer, etc. I recommend you learn the basics of Cake first, before you start using plugins. http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog/blog.html

Comment: Thanks Moz. I have done the model and it is working. It is storing the ratings with the model name as song details. However, I got some confusion with the model_id thing. I need to have the song/Album ID in this place so that I can identify the specified item. I have tried to pass the song_id as model_id. But then it is returning error as the Error: The model_id 21 of songRating does not exist.I think i need to have one more column in the table for specifying the song/album ID. can you please advice..?

Comment: The `model_id` is in the `ratings` table. This references the `id` in your `songs` table.

Comment: I have added the hasmany to the Album model and the albums table has got the ID in the name album_id. Also I have added the average and votes fields to the table. But now it is showing error that is  1054: Unknown column 'Album.id' in 'where clause'.

Comment: @AlwinAugustin it just needs to be `id`, not `album_id`